# In Django, can a url tag have an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

BACKGROUND: I'm learning Django by working on a simple to-do-list app using Django 1.11. The app has "groups" and "items", where items are the individual to-do items and every item belongs to exactly one group. The URLs may end up working something like this:

```
# snippet from urls.py
url(r'^groups$', views.all_groups, name="all_groups"),
url(r'^groups/(\d+)/$', views.view_group, name="view_group"),
url(r'^items$', views.all_items, name="all_items"),
url(r'^items/(\d+)/$', views.view_item, name="view_item"),
```

Each of the above pages would display a one or two column table (e.g. all items, or all items in a specific group, etc.), where each table element would be a link to a page to show either a specific group or a specific item.

I have a separate view for each of the above URLs, but I was able to have a single HTML template to render each table successfully. Depending on the URL, there are either 0 or 1 arguments to the URL tag:  {% url 'my_url' %} or {% url 'my_url' arg1 %}

Here is a snippet of the HTML template that can render the table with an arbitrary number of rows and columns, but at most two arguments for the url tag:

```
# lists.html - works for several different views
# every table entry is a dictionary with an 'page_ref' key and a 'display_text' key

<table>
    {% for row in url_table %}
      <tr>
        {% for col in row %}
          {% if col.arg2 %}
          <td><a href="{% url col.page_ref col.arg1 col.arg2 %}">{{col.display_text}}</a></td>
          {% elif col.arg1 %}
          <td><a href="{% url col.page_ref col.arg1 %}">{{col.display_text}}</a></td>
          {% else %}
          <td><a href="{% url col.page_ref %}">{{col.display_text}}</a></td>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {%  endfor %}
</table>
```

MY QUESTIONS:

1) My code in the HTML template to handle {% url 'my_url' %} vs. {% url 'my_url' arg1 %} vs. {% url 'my_url' arg1 arg2 %} works but it's ugly and limited to at most 2 levels deep on the URL. That is probably fine for what I want, but I don't like the code. Is there a cleaner way to handle an arbitrary number of arguments? When I tried simply not passing arg1/arg2 if not needed, I got an exception about not being able to reverse '' (or some similar error message).

2) In general, is it a bad idea to make a generic template like this? I.e., it is a better practice to have one specific HTML template per view, without making it more general? My guess is no, but I figured that I'd ask.

I can provide the view code as well, but I don't think that it is needed for my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have different views, but you are using same template

> So what you can do is ***remove conditions from template*** and
>   ***send same context variable name*** from each view containing different absolute url with respect to your view.

```
# view1 no arguments
class AllGroupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/your.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_url'] = reverse('all_groups')
        return context
#view2 one argument
class GroupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/your.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_url'] = reverse('view_group', args=[arg1])
        return context
...
#view3 two argument
class ItemView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/your.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_url'] = reverse('view_item', args=[arg1, arg2])
        return context
```

In html just use this variable

```
# use my_url absolute: http://localhost:8000/...
<td><a href="{{ my_url }}">{{display_text}}</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try, although I'll need to switch to class-based views (which I would like to learn anyway). Once I get it working, I'll accept the answer. I did try to mark the answer as useful, but I don't have enough points to have it register publicly (this was my first SO question...).

Comment: @DaveB you can do the same with function based views as well. the thing to focus is, create url in views itself  so that we can remove overhead from template.

Comment: It's almost working (in my function based views). I needed to use tweak your syntax in the reverse function to:
   reverse('view_name', args=[arg1])

But I'm getting a NoReverseMatch exception:
   Reverse for '/app/items/1/' not found. '/app/items/1/' is not a valid view function or pattern name

However, that *is* a valid URL that works when accessed directly, and I have this pattern in my urls.py file:
   url(r'^items/(\d+)/$', views.view_item, name="view_item")
I'll keep digging, but let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you declared namespaces to urls? if yes you have to use it like `reverse('items:view_item', args=[arg1])` here `items` is namespace

Comment: Ugh, I found the dumb mistake on my end. I mistakenly left my template href as `{% url my_url %}` instead of changing it to `{{my_url}}` as you described. Works now, and much cleaner. Thanks so much for your help!